# pulling out unique_ptr from unique_ptr<T,Deleter>

Tags: c++, c++11

Can someone please advise on how to return the unique pointer from a templatised unique pointer pool with a custom deletor.

In the code snippet below i am using ObjectPool.h  as my template class to get a stack of unique pointers . 
I am using ObjectPool to create a sharedpool object in DBConnection.h  and later in DBConnection.cpp i am simply returning the object to DBExec .

I get compile errors in DBConnection.cpp related to conversion of pointer with deleter to normal unique pointer.

```
> Class that will manage connection objects. 
**DBConnectionPool.h**
#ifndef DBCONNECTIONPOOL_H
#define DBCONNECTIONPOOL_H
#include "DBExec.h"
#include "ObjectPool.h"
class DBConnectionPool {
    static SharedPool<DBExec> pool;
    static DBConnectionPool* instance;
    DBConnectionPool& operator=(const DBConnectionPool&);
    DBConnectionPool(const DBConnectionPool&);;
    DBConnectionPool(){};
public:
    ...
    **static std::unique_ptr<DBExec> getQueryObject();**
};



#endif /* DBCONNECTIONPOOL_H */

**DBConnection.cpp**
>implementation of getQueryObject 
 **std::unique_ptr<DBExec>  DBConnectionPool::getQueryObject() {
    return std::move(pool.acquire());
}**

/* Class that manages the unique pointer */ 
**ObjectPool.h**
#ifndef OBJECTPOOL_H
#define OBJECTPOOL_H
#include <memory>
#include <stack>
#include <mutex>
#include <assert.h>
template <class T>
class SharedPool {

/* Class that manages the unique pointer */ 
public:
    using ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)> >;

    SharedPool() {
    }

    virtual ~SharedPool() {
    }

    void add(std::unique_ptr<T> t) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>  lck (mt);
        pool_.push(std::move(t));
    }

    ptr_type acquire() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>  lck (mt);
        assert(!pool_.empty());
        ptr_type tmp(pool_.top().release(),
                [this](T * ptr) {
                    this->add(std::unique_ptr<T>(ptr));
                });
        pool_.pop();
        return std::move(tmp);
    }

    bool empty() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>  lck (mt);
        return pool_.empty();
    }

    size_t size() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>  lck (mt);
        return pool_.size();
    }
    std::stack<std::unique_ptr<T>>& getPoolStack () {
        return pool_;
    }
private:
> thread safe 
    std::mutex mt;
    std::stack<std::unique_ptr<T> > pool_;
};

#endif /* OBJECTPOOL_H */
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal example.

Comment: When you say "convert" are you okay that the new pointer will not use the correct *deleter*?

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr<T,D>` and `std::unique_ptr<T>` are unrelated types (unless `D=std::default_delete<T>`).  So you need to specify the type of the deleter in all your typedefs.

The next problem is you can't actually type out the type of your deleter, since it's a lambda type.  So you may have to switch from a lambda to a named callable type.

```
template <class T>
class SharedPool {
public:
    class Deleter {
    public:
        void operator()(T* ptr) const {
            pool->add(std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>(ptr));
        }
    private:
        explicit Deleter(SharedPool* pool) : pool(pool) {}
        SharedPool* pool;
        friend class SharedPool<T>;
    };
    using ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>;
```

You might also consider using `std::shared_ptr` since it type-erases its deleter type, but you don't seem to need the sharedness.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get a regular `unique_ptr` from one that has a custom deleter. This is not possible because returning a `unique_ptr` from another `unique_ptr` would violate the uniqueness of that pointer. Your only option would be to convert it to something, where the deleter is hidden from the type (i.e., type erasure).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is type erasure, or at least partial type erasure. A simple solution would be to just use `std::shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<T>(new T, custom_deleter);
```

This would provide some overhead over `std::unique_ptr`, though some overhead is unavoidable.